# How to find out if a specific file was accessed by a process and denied access?

Tags: file-permissions, windows-event-log

I was recently trying to install an SSL certificate and I was unaware of which account was being used on IIS to access it.

I thought that maybe if I looked in the `Security` log I would find out what account was trying to access the certificate.

Obviously the `Audit Failure` keyword would be in the filter, but what about finding the path to the certificate file?